# How to write below logic in Generic way?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, generic-programming

I have a model like below

```
public sealed class Person
{
        public string MobileNo { get; set; }
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
}
```

In my implmentation class, I have a method which takes an `IEnumerable` as a parameter

```
public string PersonList(string listName, IEnumerable<Person> persons)
{
   dictionary.Add("name", new String[1] { listname }); 
   dictionary.Add("list", persons.ToArray());

    PrivateMethod("personList", dictionary);
}
```

I have another private method

```
private string PrivateMethod(string value, Dictionary<string, object[]> parameters)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object[]> kvp in parameters)
    {
           Person[] persons = kvp.Value.Cast<Person>().ToArray();

           [...]
    }

[...]
}
```

I want to make this above method reusable, and don't want to put **"Person"** model tightly-coupled.

Can I use **dynamic** ?

```
ContactList(string listName, IEnumerable<dynamic> persons)
```

And within the private method

`dynamic[] persons = kvp.Value.Cast<`**How to pass model here**`>().ToArray();`

**Solution:**

This will work, great.

```
 dynamic[] persons = kvp.Value.Cast<dynamic>().ToArray();
```

Thanks to  **usr** &  **Rune FS**

Comment: What do you want to do with `persons`? What about `.Cast<dynamic>()`?

Comment: @usr: Will it `.Cast<dynamic>()` work?

Comment: @ShubhajyotiGhosh try :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using "Interfaces" in c#? you can cast any object to any type as long as they are all derived to the same type of interface.

```
interface IPerson
{
    string MobileNo { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
}

class Person : IPerson
{
    public string MobileNo { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

class execute
{
    private Dictionary<string, object[]> dictionary = new Dictionary<string,object[]>();

    public void run()
    {
        List<IPerson> persons = new List<IPerson>();
        persons.Add(new Person()
        {
            LastName = "asdf",
            Name = "asdf",
            MobileNo = "123123"
        });

        persons.Add(new Person()
        {
            LastName = "aaaa",
            Name = "dddd",
            MobileNo = "1231232"
        });

        string x = PersonList("somelistname", persons);
    }


    public string PersonList(string listName, IEnumerable<IPerson> persons)
    {
        //dictionary.Add("name", new String[1] { listName });
        dictionary.Add("list", persons.ToArray());

        return PrivateMethod("personList", dictionary);
    }

    private string PrivateMethod(string value, Dictionary<string, object[]> parameters)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object[]> kvp in parameters)
        {
            IPerson[] persons = kvp.Value.Cast<IPerson>().ToArray();

        }

        return "somestring";
    }
```

Comment: Nice approach, thanks. Actually I used Interface in the original code block. And If I am not wrong, your approach satisfy DI standard.

Comment: Note that this solution, while sufficient for the OP, still limits you to -in this case- the IPerson interface, whereas generics are much more powerful re. the topic.

Answer (score 4):

You could make the `PrivateMethod` generic:

```
private string PrivateMethod<T>(string value, Dictionary<string, object[]> parameters)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object[]> kvp in parameters)
    {
           T[] items = kvp.Value.Cast<T>().ToArray();
           [...]
    }

    [...]
}
```

Comment: Then I have to make class as Generic, like `Sample<T>` . Otherwise How I pass T into Private method ?

Comment: Like this: `PrivateMethod<Person>("personList", dictionary);`.

Comment: If I write this `PrivateMethod<Person>`, then I have to take the reference of the Model within the implementation class. Which I don't want. As because right now it is Person. but it can be any thing depends on need.

Comment: @ShubhajyotiGhosh: I'm not sure if you understand. You can call the `PrivateMethod` with any type you want (that's what `<T>` stands for), as it will be replaced with the type you pass along to the method (like `Person`). I suggest you read up on [Generics over at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172192.aspx).